# Disable item if input has value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 input. First input with `url` type. Second input with `file` type. I want to make disable first input when second has value. The same behavior when second input has value. I tried next code but it don't work correctly. Where is my mistake?

```js
 $("#src").keyup(function(){
        if($('#src').val()){
            $("#src_url").toggleClass("disabled-field");
        }
    });
    $("#src_url").keyup(function(){
        if($('#src_url').val()){
            $("#src").toggleClass("disabled-field");
        }
    });
```

```css
 .disabled-field{
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="src_url" class="form-control" id="src_url" type="url">
    
    <input name="src" id="src" accept=".pdf, .zip, .rar, .doc, .docx, .rtf" type="file">
```

**Solution:**

```
$("#src_url").on("input", function() {
    $("#src").prop("disabled", !!$('#src_url').val());
    $("#src").toggleClass("disabled-field", !!$('#src_url').val());
});

$("#src").on("change", function() {
  $("#src_url").prop("disabled", !!$('#src').val());
    $("#src_url").toggleClass("disabled-field", !!$('#src').val());
});
```

Comment: *it don't work correctly* what do you mean?

Comment: If you have a solution - add it as an answer - you can answer your own question :)

Comment: @TarynEast my final solution based on T.J.Crowder's answer. So I mark his answer as correct and post my working code in question own post. It's only fair.

Comment: Good on you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're toggling the class when there's a value, so that means on one `keyup` it'll add the class, on the next `keyup` it'll remove it, etc. When there's no value, you leave it alone entirely. See: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass.

You probably wanted to use [the two-argument version](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-function-state) and no `if`:

```
$("#src_url").toggleClass("disabled-field", !!$('#src').val());
```

Note the `!!` to turn a truthy/falsy value into `true` or `false`.

---

I will note that the proper way to disable a field is the `disabled` property, not a class. To use that instead, use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$("#src_url").prop("disabled", !!$('#src').val());
```

Comment: Now that's smart, had no idea you could do that. +1 for sure

Comment: Hello, my friend! :) I tested both of your solutions right now but unfortunately they don't work. It seems to me I make something wrong again. Can you check it please: https://jsfiddle.net/NogerbekNurzhan/j0uqmgs2/ My aim: when user enter something to first input I want to disable second input. The same behavior to second input.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would be extremely grateful if you tell me how to make such trigger. I am really confused.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: You were doing it in your answer, I assumed you knew. FWIW, I'd use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) rather than the shortcut, and I'd probably use the `input` event rather than `keyup`: `$("the-input").on("input", function() { /* ... */});`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hello! Thank you very much! Finally I make working trigger for both inputs. For second input which has file type its better to use next code: `$("#src").on("change", function() {/* ... */};`